# Why is principle value of argument generally taken as $(-\pi , \pi]$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have just started reading about the Modulus and Argument of Complex Numbers. In the definition, it is said that:

If z is not equal to 0 and $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$ , then $\theta$ is the principal argument of z, written $\theta = \arg(z)$.

My question is about the interval: why do we take $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$, which, if I understand it correctly starts at $180$ degrees, namely $-\pi$ (the most left point on the $x$ axis of the zero circle), and moves counter clockwise until it reaches $180$ degrees again? Why don't we use, say, $[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Not much of an advantage, but in this principal value range, if $\arg(z) = t$ then $\arg(z^*)$ is $-t$.

Comment: @Shaun Have I incorrectly used the MathJax's symbols? I did my best :) Please, show me what I did wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `$\pi$` for $\pi$ and enclose all mathematics in `$`s

Comment: @samjoe What does asterisk refer to? Sorry, I am not not that good yet. )

Comment: Note that $-\pi<\Theta\le\pi$ because $\Theta=\pi$ is possible.

Comment: @Shaun Yes, thank you )

Comment: @Vitale $z^*$ is the conjugate of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of convention.

Comment: Thank you. What does this convention refer too, and what meaning lies behind it?

Comment: It's somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is arbitrary. This convention is related to the principal determination of the complex log function which, rather often, is defined by a cut along the negative $x$ axis.